# Reading data from a file and Writing it to a different file (Visual studio 2012)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

The problem I have is that I'm reading data from files and then I write them to file, but the very first element gets cut out. I will show you an example. Sorry for the language, however it should not interrupt with understanding what is going on, this code is kinda simple.

So the data files. From this:

```
   4 12
    Domas P 2 balta Z 0 balta R 0 balta B 0 balta V 0 balta K 0 balta P 2 juoda Z 0 juoda R 0 juoda B 0 juoda V 0 juoda K 0 juoda
    Lukas P 4 balta Z 0 balta R 0 balta B 0 balta V 0 balta K 0 balta P 4 juoda Z 0 juoda R 0 juoda B 0 juoda V 0 juoda K 0 juoda
    Tomas P 6 balta Z 0 balta R 0 balta B 0 balta V 0 balta K 0 balta P 6 juoda Z 0 juoda R 0 juoda B 0 juoda V 0 juoda K 0 juoda
    Tadas P 8 balta Z 0 balta R 0 balta B 0 balta V 0 balta K 0 balta P 8 juoda Z 0 juoda R 0 juoda B 0 juoda V 0 juoda K 0 juoda
```

I am getting this:

```
P      2 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta    K      0 balta    P      2 juoda    P      4 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta
Lukas    P      4 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta    K      0 balta    P      4 juoda    P      6 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta
Tomas    P      6 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta    K      0 balta    P      6 juoda    P      8 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta
Tadas    P      8 balta    Z      0 balta    R      0 balta    B      0 balta    V      0 balta    K      0 balta    P      8 juoda    Z      0 juoda    R      0 juoda    B      0 juoda    V      0 juoda    K      0 juoda
```

The very first element "Domas" got cut out. If it would be an int type variable, it would show -884646546 or something like that. As i already know it means the program can't find anything and writes and empty space or that random negative stuff. However I don't know how to fix this, which is the problem. Thanks for any help!

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const char CD1fv[] = "Komplektai.txt";
const char CD2fv[] = "Parama.txt";
const char CRfv[] = "Turnyras.txt";

class Komplektas
{
private:
    int eile;
    int kiek;
    string fig;
    string spalva;
    string vardas;
public:
    Komplektas(int k = 0, string f = "", string s = "") :
    kiek(k), fig(f), spalva(s) { }
    ~Komplektas() { }
    void Deti(int k, string f, string s) { kiek = k; fig = f, spalva = s; }
    void Eile(int e) { eile = e; }
    void Vardas(string v) { vardas = v; }
    string ImtiVarda() { return vardas; }
    int ImtiEile() { return eile; }
    string ImtiFigura() { return fig; }
    int ImtiKieki() { return kiek; }
    string ImtiSpalva() {return spalva; }
};

class Matrica
{
public:
    static const int CMaxEil = 100;
    static const int CMaxSt = 7;
private:
    Komplektas A[CMaxEil][CMaxSt];
    int n;
    int m;
public:
    Matrica(int nn = 0, int mm = 0) : n(nn), m(mm) { }
    ~Matrica() { }
    int ImtiN() { return n; }
    int ImtiM() { return m; }
    void DetiN(int nn) {n = nn; }
    void DetiM( int mm) { m = mm; }
    void DetiReiksme( int i, int j, Komplektas r) {A[i][j] = r; }
    Komplektas ImtiReiksme(int i, int j) { return A[i][j]; }
};
void Ivesti1(const char fv[], Matrica & A);
void Ivesti2(const char fv[], Matrica & A);
void Spausdinti1(const char fv[], Matrica & A);
void Spausdinti2(const char fv[], Matrica & A);


int main()
{
    Matrica Figuros;

    Ivesti1(CD1fv, Figuros);
    Spausdinti1(CRfv, Figuros);

    Ivesti2(CD2fv, Figuros);
    Spausdinti2(CRfv, Figuros);

    cout << "Pradiniai duomenys isspausdinti faile " << CRfv << endl;
    cout << "Programa baige darba" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void Ivesti1(const char fv[], Matrica & A)
{
    int n, m;
    string spalva;
    string fig;
    int eile, kiek;
    Komplektas komplektas;
    ifstream fd(fv);
    fd >> n >> m;
    A.DetiN(n);
    A.DetiM(m);
    fd.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fd >> eile;
        komplektas.Eile(eile);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            fd >> fig >> kiek >> spalva;
            komplektas.Deti(kiek, fig, spalva);
            A.DetiReiksme(i, j, komplektas);
        }

    }

    fd.close();
}

void Spausdinti1(const char fv[], Matrica & A)
{
    Komplektas x;
    ofstream fr(fv, ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.ImtiN(); i++) {
        fr << i+1;
        for (int j = 0; j < A.ImtiM(); j++) {
            x = A.ImtiReiksme(i , j);
            fr << setw(5) << x.ImtiFigura() << " " << right
                << setw(6) << x.ImtiKieki() << " " << x.ImtiSpalva();
        }
        fr << endl;
    }
    fr << endl;
    fr.close();
}

void Ivesti2(const char fv[], Matrica & A)
{
    int n, m;
    string spalva;
    string fig;
    string vardas;
    int eile, kiek;
    Komplektas komplektas;
    ifstream fd(fv);
    fd >> n >> m;
    A.DetiN(n);
    A.DetiM(m);
    fd.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fd >> vardas;
        komplektas.Vardas(vardas);
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            fd >> fig >> kiek >> spalva;
            komplektas.Deti(kiek, fig, spalva);
            A.DetiReiksme(i, j, komplektas);
        }
    }
    fd.close();
}

void Spausdinti2(const char fv[], Matrica & A)
{
    Komplektas x;
    ofstream fr(fv, ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.ImtiN(); i++) {
        fr << x.ImtiVarda();
        for (int j = 0; j < A.ImtiM(); j++) {
            x = A.ImtiReiksme(i , j);
            fr << setw(5) << x.ImtiFigura() << " " << right
                << setw(6) << x.ImtiKieki() << " " << x.ImtiSpalva();
        }
        fr << endl;
    }
    fr << endl;
    fr.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reading of the file "Komplektai.txt" is out of sync with its format.
You first read (in Ivesti1) n and m two integers. Fine no problem. The you ignore a single character. I don't understand that. You don't have to handle '\n' yourself. Next you enter a for-loop. The first thing you do in the loop is to read eile, an int. But the file position is pointing at "Domas". So, your stream enter an error state and all of your future reads fail.

I would suggest that you step through your code in the debugger, Visual Studio has an excellent debugger. Notice how variables are modified when reads succeeds.

In C++ the general idiom is to attempt to read something, then verify the read succeeded before proceeding.

```
for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    fd >> fig >> kiek >> spalva;
    if (!fd) {
        std::cerr << "something went wrong" << std::endl;
        break;    // Can't continue, the stream is in a bad state
    }
    // Here we know the previous reads succeeded and we can use the read data
    ....
}
```